# Changes were not applied in CKEditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I tried to change CKEditor configuration.

What I need - my `<i>` tag now do not stay after update post, and CKEditor automatically deletes it.

I tried to reset caches - does not help.

My new line in `config.js`:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.removeFormatTags['i'] = false;
```

My code before saving:

```html
<div class="sn-container">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope">&nbsp;</i>
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter">&nbsp;</i>
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook">&nbsp;</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

My code, when I try to update:

```html
<div class="sn-container">&nbsp;</div>
```

Also I tried to field tag with value:

Results when I tried to edit/update:

```html
<div class="sn-container">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/andrii.kozubenko" target="_blank">
    <em>&nbsp;</em>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/andrii.kozubenko" target="_blank">
    <em>&nbsp;</em>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/andrii.kozubenko" target="_blank">
    <em>&nbsp;</em>
  </a>
</div>
```

`<i>` tag was replaced with `<em>` tag.

Why are the changes not accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1908696

```js
CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push( /<i class[\s\S]*?\>/g ); //allows beginning <i> tag
CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push( /<\/i>/g ); //allows ending </i> tag
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try using below code:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraAllowedContent : 'i(*)', //allow any class of i
    coreStyles_italic : {
        element: 'i',
        overrides : 'em'
    }   
});
```

By default [basic styles](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_basicstyles) are set to use `<em>` tags and override `<i>`. Please see: https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-coreStyles_italic.

The `extraAllowedContent` is needed if you are using [ACF](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf).